# Set default value of ListPreference via service

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I have 1 service for notification and after i received notification i want to set preference to desire value. Is it possible? how?

and because it is a service so I can't use

```
ListPreference  lp = (ListPreference) findPreference ("key");
```

any idea? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
prefs.edit().putString("key", "val").commit();
```